# I upload images with html form but I can't visualise them once displayed with the servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, netbeans

The task requires to upload an image with an html form and send it back with a servlet.

This is the form code:

'''

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet'  href='styles.css'>
        <title>What's new?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-container-col">
        <form class="basic_form" action="Servlet2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <label class="form_labels">Post something new</label>
                <br>
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
                <br><br>
                <textarea name='newstatement' rows=5 cols=50>Type here...
                </textarea>
                <div class="flex-container-col">
                    <input class="form_buttons" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

'''

this is the servlet one:

'''

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet2", urlPatterns = {"/Servlet2"})
@MultipartConfig
public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            
            Part part = request.getPart("file");
            String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName();
            
            String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/"+"media"+File.separator+fileName);

            InputStream is = part.getInputStream();
            
            boolean succs = UploadFile(is, path);
            if(succs){
                out.println("file uploaded to this directory: "+path);
                out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<head>");
                out.println("<title>Servlet Servlet1</title>");            
                out.println("</head>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<img src=\"media/"+fileName+" alt=\"\" \n"+">");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>"); 
            }
            else{
                out.println("error");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public boolean UploadFile(InputStream is, String path) {
        boolean test = false;
        
        try{
            byte[] byt = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read();
            FileOutputStream fops = new FileOutputStream(path);
            fops.write(byt);
            fops.flush();
            fops.close();
            
            test = true;
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return test;
    }

    

}
```

'''

The problem is that when I upload an image I can't see it displayed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D539m.png)

But I only see it as a tiny icon. Going to the folder in which I saved it I see:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OqXe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The bytes of the uploaded image are never read:

`is.read()` returns the next available byte on the InputStream, but the code doesn't capture it (like in `int b = is.read()`.

It also looks like you planned to create a buffer big enough to hold all bytes (`byt`), probably to use it with `is.read(byt)`, but that is nog guaranteed to work because `is.available()` might not return the full length of the InputStream, as the documentation for [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) states:

> It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

Something like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (-1 != (bytesRead = is.read(buffer))) {
   fops.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

will probably work, but why bother? Just use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)):

```
Path nioPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path);
Files.copy(is, nioPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

and let the library do the work.